# Calling function inside of function throws error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a "you think of a number and the computer has to guess it" type program. My code is here: http://pastebin.com/6Ny01PJV, and whenever it calls a function from another function it either ends the program or errors out.

```
def guess():
    global guess
    guess = choice(list)
    if guess in cache:
        guess()
else:
    pass
    print (guess)
    cache.append(guess)

def check(guess):
    global check
    check = input("Was " + str(guess) + " the number? (y, n) ").lower()
    if check == "n":
        global wrong
        wrong = input("Lower or higher? ").lower

elif check == "y":
    playAgain = input ("I guessed the number! Play again? (y, n)")
    if playAgain == "y":
#Right here it will error out with a TypeError
            main()
    if playAgain == "n":
            exit()
    else:
        print("Please answer in the format 'y' or 'n'"

def reguess():
    if wrong == "lower":
        reguess = choice(list < guess)
#Here it will end the program, no crash, just no error given
        check(reguess)
    elif wrong == "higher":
#The same happens here
        check(reguess)
        reguess = choice(list > guess)
```

Whenever I type either 'higher' or 'lower', it ends the program.

Am I doing it wrong or is there an error in my code that I am not seeing?

Comment: Please don't use PasteBin. Add your code to the question as a [mcve]

Comment: Also, add the traceback... I see you've overwritten the `list` function and not really knowing how `global` works

Comment: Python is not Pascal in which you have to assign value to function name to return it from function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep doing the same error over and over. I'll try to explain.

```
global list  # already is globally defined on next line 
list = list(range(0,11))  # list() is a function, you overwrite it here 
print (list)

global cache # not necessary, again already global 
cache = []

print ("Write down a number anywhere from 1-10.\nThe computer will try to guess your number.")

def guess():   # this defines a global function 'guess' 
    global guess  # probably gets resolved to the function 
    guess = choice(list)  # you overwrite the 'guess' function
```

Now, as I said, you keep having the same problem. You're making your variables overwrite the functions. You're then calling those variables as functions, as if you didn't overwrite anything.

So, `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.` or *something* isn't callable.

Suggestion: remove `global` in favor of `return` the value from each function

Another problem I see

```
reguess = choice(list < guess)
```

Not clear what you expect that to do... `list < guess` is a boolean and you can't `random.choice` that.

Comment: This fixed half of my problem. I am still getting the problem where typing "lower" or "higher" will still end the program.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` means that you've done the equivalent of this:

```
def a(x):
    return x+1
a = 1
a(2)
```

Here, we've defined a function with the name 'a', then redefined 'a' to be an int, then tried to call our function. This doesn't work because the name 'a' no longer refers to the function, but now refers to the integer 1.

Look at your code and I'm betting you'll see something similar to the above.